# Forecasts with specific VAR model lags

Tags: r, time-series, restrict

Thanks in advance.  In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661397/choosing-specific-lags-in-arima-or-var-model/22662480?noredirect=1#comment34530676_22662480), I asked the question of how to choose specific lags in a VAR model.  After a quick reply and information of the 'restrict' and 'coef' functions I was able to successfully run a VAR model with the specific lags I wanted.  However, what's the code I need to use the restricted VAR model to make forecasts?

Sample of my code is below:

```
 ##Attempt to Restrict VAR Coefficients
 ##VAR has 5 lags with three variables plus constant and 11 seasonal dummies.

 library("vars")
 var1 <- VAR(DVARmat, p = 5, type ="const", season = 12)
 restrict <- matrix (c(1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,
                       1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,
                       1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0),
                     nrow = 3, ncol = 27, byrow = T)
 var1_restrict <- coef(restrict(var1, method ="man", resmat = restrict))
 var1_restrict
```

I know the forecast code after a normal VAR, but can't seem to fudge the restricted VAR into it.  Thanks again.

Comment: I suppose you use `predict` for unrestricted VAR model, but then, since `restrict(...)` also returns an object of class `varest`, you should be able to successfully use `predict` on `restrict(...)` too. Maybe you were trying `predict(coef(restrict(...)))` or something like that?

Comment: @Julius okay I can see clearly now.  I need to get used to the R terminology with Objects and Classes.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer to your question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After generating the restricted coefficient matrix `restrict`, you can use `predict` on `restrict(...)` since `restrict(...)` also returns an object of class `varest` :

```
 ##Attempt to Restrict VAR Coefficients
     ##VAR has 5 lags with three variables plus constant and 11 seasonal dummies.

         library("vars")
         var1 <- VAR(DVARmat, p = 5, type ="const", season = 12)
         restrict <- matrix (c(1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,
                               1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,
                               1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0),
                             nrow = 3, ncol = 27, byrow = T)
         var1_restrict <- coef(restrict(var1, method ="man", resmat = restrict))
         var1_restrict

         expostrestrict <- predict(restrict(var1, method="man", resmat = restrict), n.ahead = 13, ci=.95)
```

Note that `restrict(var1, method="man", resmat = restrict)` is an object that could be generated, thus if one prefers they may also use the following :

```
restrict_var <- restrict(var1, method="man", resmat = restrict)
expostrestrict <- predict(restrict_var, n.ahead = 13, ci=.95)
```